# Can I use the same variable in multiple functions in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, discord-buttons

I am trying to make a bot, that can do the following:
I want to join a vc that is full
I run a command
the bot makes a button
If someone that is in the vc presses the button, I get moved in

I have this code:
For the MoveUser function I need the whotomove and client variables from the movemeto command
How can I get them into a variable and use them in the function?
(also, apologies if this question is badly phrased, I am quite new)

```
async def MoveUser(interraction : discord.Interaction):
    channel = interraction.user.voice.channel
    user = interraction.user 
    print(channel)
    print(user) 
    await user.move_to(channel)
```

```
class MoveMenuButtons(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(timeout=None)


    @discord.ui.button(label="Accpet", style=discord.ButtonStyle.green)
    async def Accept(self, interraction:discord.Interaction, Button: discord.ui.Button,):
        await interraction.channel.send(content="accepted")
        await MoveUser(interraction,)

    @discord.ui.button(label="Decline", style=discord.ButtonStyle.red)
    async def Decline(self, interraction:discord.Interaction, Button: discord.ui.Button):
        await interraction.channel.send(content="declined")
```

```
@client.tree.command(name="movemeto", description="moves you to another voice channel")
async def movemeto(interraction : discord.Interaction, channel : discord.VoiceChannel):
    whotomove = interraction.user
    print (whotomove)
    print (channel)
    if(interraction.user.voice):
        await interraction.response.send_message(content=f"{whotomove} wants to be moved to the channel {channel}", view=MoveMenuButtons())
    else:
        await interraction.response.send_message("Join a voice channel to run this command")
```

I attempted to pass it as (I think it's called a parameter(the thing in the bracket)) but the buttons don't seem to support it

Comment: To share a variable, you can use multiple thing. You can make it global (to access it everywhere), you can also use an environment variable (os.environ, only to read one). In your case, it can be nice to use a threading.Lock mechanism while accessing a variable also

Comment: But these two functions are not related, right?  Who is calling `movemeto`?  Is that a separate transaction?

Comment: @TimRoberts movemeto is called by a discord command(hope that makes sense)

Comment: But what's the flow?  A user enters "movemeto" to ask to be moved.  Then, at some future point, an administrator presses the "Accept" button (or "Accpet" if you don't fix the spelling) to make the move happen?  For that to work, "movemeto"` needs to write the pending move request to a file somewhere, so that the information can be used later on (potentially MUCH later, right?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass these variables and save them in your MoveMenuButtons view through the `__init__` method:

```py
class MoveMenuButtons(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self, to_channel: discord.VoiceChannel):
        self.to_channel = to_channel
        super().__init__(timeout=None)

    @discord.ui.button(label="Accpet", style=discord.ButtonStyle.green)
    async def accept(self, interraction:discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button,):
        await interraction.response.edit_message(content="accepted", view=None)
        await self.interraction.user.move_to(self.to_channel)

    @discord.ui.button(label="Decline", style=discord.ButtonStyle.red)
    async def decline(self, interraction:discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
        await interraction.response.edit_message(content="declined", view=None)
    

@client.tree.command(name="movemeto", description="moves you to another voice channel")
async def movemeto(interraction : discord.Interaction, channel : discord.VoiceChannel):
    whotomove = interraction.user
    print (whotomove)
    print (channel)
    if interraction.user.voice:
        view = MoveMenuButtons(channel)
        await interraction.response.send_message(content=f"{whotomove} wants to be moved to the channel {channel}", view=view)
    else:
        await interraction.response.send_message("Join a voice channel to run this command")
```